# CryptoKit - Encrypt with public key?

Tags: sjcl, apple-cryptokit

To give you the context, there is a developer who develops the API of the project and there is a part of the json that will be encrypted.
So I have to decipher his content.
He has listed all the functions that I will need on the iOs side.

So I have his javascript code and I have to redo the equivalent in swift.
He uses the JS library (SJCL) : https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/

I'm trying to encrypt some text with a public key, but I can't.

First, I generated the private/public keys

```
let keypair = P256.Signing.PrivateKey() // generation of a key pair

 let private_key = keypair.rawRepresentation.base64EncodedString()   // private key
 print(private_key)
 print("------------")

 let public_key = keypair.publicKey // public key - DATA
 print(public_key)
 print("------------")

 let publicKeyString = public_key.rawRepresentation.base64EncodedString() // public key - STRING - easy to share
 print(publicKeyString)
```

Now, I'm trying to encrypt a text with the public key..

Here, his javascript code :

```
var c256 = sjcl.ecc.curves.c256;
var publickeyBas64ToBits = sjcl.codec.base64.toBits(publickey);

console.log(c256);
console.log(publickey);
console.log(publickeyBas64ToBits);

var pub = new sjcl.ecc.elGamal.publicKey(
                    c256, 
                    publickeyBas64ToBits
                )
var ciphertext = sjcl.encrypt(pub, message)
return ciphertext
```

I don't understand how to do the same thing in swift with CryptoKit :/

Can you help me please ? :)

Comment: Public key encryption is totally standardized. Browsers & servers do it in many, different languages, and it works. So I would not bother trying to transcode their JavaScript. Just search for how to do public key encryption in Swift and follow that example, and plug in c256 and ElGamal if those aren't default.

Comment: Do you have a link or an example to guide me? I tried several things but I never succeed :/

Comment: The javascript code does not make any sense for several reasons. 1) there is no such thing as “encrypt with public key” REALLY, ALL encryption is Symmetric. What one means when one says Assymetric Encryption is to do two things: A) Alice performa Diffie-Hellman KeyExchange with her Private Key and Bobs Public Key, to form a shared Symmetric Key and B) using this shared Symmetric key Alice can encrypt some message using AES GCM for example. But in the JavaScript code that is not happening. It MUST happen. Otherwise insecure. Continue in part 2 below

Comment: Part 2: insecure if we encrypt the message with just the public key (used as Symmetric encryption key (AES)) and then broadcast that key. Then anyone can decrypt it. Furthermore is the JavaScript incorrect because it involves ElGamal. Which just complicates matters. ElGamal should not be used at all.

Answer (score 1):

Given two KeyPairs, lets call them Alice and Bob - Alice would like to encrypt a message M that only Bob should be able to decrypt (and Alice too):

You are given Bobs public key as either 33 or 64 or possibly 65 bytes (compressed form, X||Y form (raw) or uncompressed 04||X||Y), construct a `P256.KeyAgreement.PublicKey` from the bytes. This assumes that the bytes are not base64 encoded, but rather on hex format (see this for hex String to Data conversion: https://gist.github.com/nicklockwood/81b9f122f3db9e7132be7bd61d0c0cea ). If Base64 instead of hex, decode it first and ensure 33, 64, or 65 bytes. If 65 bytes, drop the first byte and use [this initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/p256/keyagreement/publickey/3237686-init) if 33 bytes use [this initializer instead](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/p256/keyagreement/publickey/3237685-init)

Having access to Alice private key, `P256.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey` - if you have earlier created a signing private key (`P256.Signing.PrivateKey`), you can simply convert back and forth between them using the property `rawRepresentation` and the initializer `init(rawRepresentation` on both - perform the keyagreement to form a SharedSecret. By calling

`let sharedSecret = aliceKeyAgreementPrivateKey.sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement(with: bobsKeyAgreementPublicKey)`

Now lets create an AES.GCM.SealedBox from the message bytes

`let encryptedMessage = try AES.GCM.SealedBox(combined: messageData)`
Where messageData is `Data` from either base64 decoding a base64 encoded string or Data from hex string.

Now lets create a SymmetricKey we can use to AES.GCM decrypt - “open” - the sealedBox.

`let aesDecryptionKey = sharedSecret.withUnsafeBytes { SymmetricKey($0) }`
Or using [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/sharedsecret/3238005-x963derivedsymmetrickey) instead of `withUnsafeBytes`  or [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/sharedsecret/3238003-hkdfderivedsymmetrickey), but then you need to come up with a good salt. These methods are much much safer then withUnsafeBytes, but makes my explaination a bit longer and more complex, so I leave it to your system to determine salt.this have to match what the sender used to encrypt the message of course!! As in both the SharedSecret by KeyAgreement AND the derivation of the SymmetricKey for encryption/decryption has to match..

Finally we can open the SealedBox!

`let decryptedData = try AES.GCM.open(sealedBox, using: aesDecryptionKey)`

And if the data was some plaintext message you might wanna decode it so it becomes readable, e.g. If it was UTF8 encoded:

`let decryptedMessage = String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8)!`